# if after if condition in a form validation how can I make it better

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm refactoring my code to make it better and shorter. Im making a register form that validate user inputs using materialize but I dont feel too good about my code structure which contains if after if as much as possible the code should not contain deeply nested condition.

```
$('#full_name').on('input', function() {
var input=$(this);
var is_name=input.val().trim();
var inputLength = is_name.length;
var regEx = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;

  if(is_name){
    $(".helper-text").text('correct');
  }
  if(inputLength < 3) {
    $(".helper-text").text('too little words');
  }
  if(inputLength > 50) {
    $(".helper-text").text('too many words');
  }
  if(!regEx.test(is_name)) {
    $(".helper-text").text('only accept letters');
  }
  if(!is_name) {
    $(".helper-text").text('*required fields');
 }


});
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't 'deeply nested'. Just - as you say - if after if. Looks like you need to change to 'else if' for each 'if' after the first one though.

Comment: I need to check every condition that is why I put it in a separate if's

Comment: In which case it would make more sense to use `append()` instead of `text()`, otherwise only the last error will be shown.

Comment: You could take a look into form validation libraries. For example [jquery-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-validation) or any other js library (let's say [parsleyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parsleyjs)). However - if you don't have many forms, its perfectly fine to do it as simple as possible (many ifs) and later refactor it.

Comment: @JordanEnev yeah I've look into that but as much as possible I'm avoiding the usage of libraries or API's because of company standards

Comment: Most of the libraries have MIT license, so I guess you won't have any problems. However if so - you can look into their source code and take further insights.